# How to get utf-8 chars from mysql to visual fox pro

Tags: mysql, utf-8, visual-foxpro

I have a MYSQL table with a single column. The database, table and column collation are set to: utf8_general_ci.
Using a browser, I insert strings in that field. If I insert chars like: şţăîâ or ŞŢĂÎÂ, it is inserted ok. I can see them ok using Phpmyadmin.
My problem is when I want that table in Visual Fox Pro.
I'm using this:

```
conn_str="Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=database_name;User=user_name;Password=pass;Option=71305256"
conn=SQLSTRINGCONNECT(conn_str)    

SQLEXEC(conn,"SET CHARACTER SET utf8")
SQLEXEC(conn,"SET COLLATION_CONNECTION='utf8_general_ci'")

SQLEXEC (conn,"select * from table_name","Cursor")
```

But in the vfp cursor, strings like şţăîâ appear like ???îâ
Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change your MySQL to some ANSI charset like CP-1252, because visual frox pro does not seem to support utf-8. See 
[What's the problem with Unicode support in Visual FoxPro](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/foxunicode/foxunicode.asp#WhatProblem)

Comment: That is not the case. If I use a Visual Fox Pro form to insert chars like ŞŢĂÎÂ or şţăîâ they are inserted ok. Also if I read the data from mysql into Visual Fox Pro form the chars appear like they were inserted (just fine). The problems only appear when chars are inserted via web browser.

Comment: What is the charset of the webpage? Check your settings and verify it in your browser. (page encoding or something like that)

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ro-ro">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"> Page encoding is ok since the chars are inserted ok via web browser

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `strings` to `binary` . e.g :

```
SQLEXEC(conn,"select cast(lastname as binary) as lastname from table_name","Cursor")
```